# Magento add to cart / customer login hidden after copy to new domain

Tags: php, apache, magento

I'm having a strange behaviour after moving a running Magento 1.7 to a new host (apache2.4.7 php5.5).

It is a copy of all the same Magento files and DB, but with new domain running on different machine.

So far:

- Admin login is working
- homepage shows up
- All CMS, product categories, menu and products work

But as soon as I **log in as customer** or **add a product to cart**, 
nothing happens:

- Login credentials request is just shown again
- Product page with add to cart button just refreshes

I can see in the backend that the customer has successfully logged into the shop and the user is online. But on frontend there is no indication of this.

So far I've tried:

- Cookie issue: hidden input in login.phtml (no change)
- Cookie timeout set to 1 day (no change)

Any hints on how should I investigate further?

Comment: Thank you for the formatting @mathielo.

Next thing I tried is disable rewrites:
In Magento backend CONFIGURATION I switched off WEBSERVER REWRITES and for Apache I "sudo a2dismod rewrite" and "restart": No change of behavior - URLs just include index.php now. 
Still looking for hits, how to debug this (I only know little about magento).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all log tables and empty cache and session folder and reindex your magento. Check it is solved your problem or not. If not check your exception and system log and also check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and would like to share it with you:

My Magento website has two stores (same products, multiple languages)
In phpMyAdmin I updated everything to the new domain already in the first run:

update core_config_data set value = 'http://newdomain.com/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data set value = 'http://newdomain.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

So the shop came up in both languages ok as described above.

BUT: I forgot to modify the values where path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain' and '../cookie_path' on per store level.

As customers can switch between the languages without loosing their cart, I had to make sure these cookie settings are correct.

Then I followed the steps from @urfusion - thanks.

So it was a cookie configuration problem.